# YAML dump inconsistent string encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Ruby version: 2.2.5
Rails version: '~> 4.0.13'

Why I and my friend have received different result when trying to convert a string to YAML using `YAML.dump` method?

```
[1] pry(main)> YAML.dump("foo")
=> "--- foo\n"
[2] pry(main)> "foo".to_yaml
=> "--- foo\n"
```

While he has:

```
[1] pry(main)> YAML.dump("foo")
=> "--- foo\n...\n"
[2] pry(main)> "foo".to_yaml
=> "--- foo\n...\n"
```

With triple dots after new line (...)

**UPDATED**

I have confirmed that my rails is using `Psych` as YAML parser engine, in rails console:

```
2.2.5 :002 > YAML
 => Psych
2.2.5 :004 > Psych.dump("foo")
 => "--- foo\n"
2.2.5 :005 > YAML.dump("foo")
 => "--- foo\n"
2.2.5 :006 >
```

But still the result is somehow different. For additional informations, I don't have any `syck` gem installed and not required it in any files in my rails project.

Comment: Did you figure out why was that? I got the same issue today and I have no idea why. It's causing some issues between different systems

Answer (score 1):

It appears "You" might be using [`syck`](https://github.com/ruby/syck) as a YAML processor while "He" is using [`psych`](https://github.com/ruby/psych). E.g.

```
 require 'syck' 
 require 'psych'
 Syck.dump("foo")
 #=> "--- foo\n"
 Psych.dump("foo")
 #=> "--- foo\n...\n"
```

Both are valid YAML parser/emitters per se although `Psych` has been preferred since 1.9 and `Syck` really only exists as a gem for backwards compatibility and was completely removed from ruby standard lib as of 2.0.0

As for why "You" are somehow using `Syck` instead I cannot say without far more information than was provided in this post.

Comment: I have checked in my rails console that YAML object is appeared to be using `Psych`. But somehow I still get the above result.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue this week and spent a great deal of time investigating the root cause. I have found that the difference of libyaml in the system will affect the dump.

For libyaml version 0.1.7, it will always include the ending characters like that, that's why you have the extra "...\n".

For libyaml version 0.2.1 and above, it supports implicit ending so those characters can be ignored